# Compare all items in two lists quickly

Tags: python

I need to compare all items in a list really quick in python. For example:
I've two list: `[1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5]` and `[1, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0]`

I've this code:

zero is the '0' in this case

```
lista = {(list1[i] != zero and list2[i] == zero) or (list1[i] == zero)
                     for i in range(min(len(list1), len(list2)))}

return all(lista)
```

My problem is: I need to do this in huge lists, like 10000 entries. Is there a way to do this like really really quick?

Comment: one loop for 10000 entries is already quick.

Comment: Linear time over unordered data is pretty much as good as you're going to get in the general sense; at least with the sort of problem you're describing.

Comment: The code might be improved with `zip`, though, rather than calculating lengths and then indexing. `all((x != 0 and y == 0) or (x == 0) for x, y in zip(list1, list2))`?

Comment: A tiny tiny improvement: in boolean logic `~A^B v A` is equivalent to `A v B`. And if your data is always numeric, you don't need an explicit comparison with `zero`. So then `not(list1[i] and list2[i])`

Comment: Using `numpy` will offer possibilities for performance boost. But if speed is important, then realise that most other popular languages will perform better.

Comment: What is the desired result of your comparison?  Do you want the differences, the similarities, or do you just need to know if they are the same in that they have the same values even if they are in different orders?

Comment: @Chris Yours gets about 2740 and 0.98 in my benchmark.

Comment: @trincot If they have lists as they say,  I suspect NumPy would be slower. And in "average" cases, where I guess the answer can be found early, NumPy would probably still be slower even on arrays, as it doesn't shortcircuit, does it? That said, if you have a NumPy solution, I'd be interested how it fares in my benchmark (and a version of it with arrays).

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to iterate over the whole list if any false condition is encountered at the beginning.

```
for a, b in zip(list1,list2):
    if a and b:
        return False
return True
```

Why `a and b` ?

Because, **A and not(B) or not(A)** is equivelant to ***not(A and B)***, that is a `True` condition, so ***A and B*** is `False` condition / `break` condition.

Result: Runs ***O(1)*** in Best case, ***O(min(m,n))*** in Worst case.

note:
`a and b` also can be written as `a!=0 and b!=0` or `not(a==0 or b ==0)`

Answer (score 0):

> Compare all items in two lists quickly

One way to do that is to **not  do that**.

By which I mean don't compare **all** items. Stop as soon as you know the answer. You use a set comprehension. Make it a generator expression instead (`(...)` instead of `{...}`). Then in your example, you already stop at the first item, never even looking at the remaining five.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools`:

```
not any(compress(list2, list1))
```

Benchmark results with a worst case:

```
3477.93 us  Pietr
1071.65 us  Anmol
 386.10 us  Kelly
```

Benchmark results with a best case:

```
3850.25 us  Pietr
   0.51 us  Anmol
   0.48 us  Kelly
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLTsMwELznK5ZDlRhZVdJKgCrlwIULFw7cqqpy2g215EfkOEIt4tuDH0mbAL4k3p3ZmbHdnO1Jq/VTY/q@NlqC5RK5BS4bbSwYbJDZJHS4RWO1Fu3YPGjZGGzbJDliDW8crckEb21BwX9WZJOAWxc0GkrIw8Y3mNt9ReSW7@CujBCmjpHni2UsEtAGbtCxGkb9WbXDcuAKDFMfmEmuMoEqsonzNPyvCCHfYYJB2xkFTIjQYCQmeVZSi/@SeAFGofIaF94MkCnCL14DC2GqzcznoPbCRItT@XfTYRR@RSHO/wkPSKWtG3zOxoOPcSK0IIP7CtXhlAlWoRg681mN4crGPrmmqjt18Km24RZpPAIaDe3gHta3KNbdnj/a@DTcIFkd2SZMmFunoDpZoSm9tZEd1dPF43JVQ9dCCgvIrFMo8MEx/JTlfq@YxP2eTPy6cDFY@qlN694eazGlsM1pTgvvsMjdCoWC5tcCGVkVTkjFb1IxJ/X9Dw)):

```
from timeit import repeat
from itertools import compress

def Pietr(list1, list2):
    zero = 0
    lista = {(list1[i] != zero and list2[i] == zero) or (list1[i] == zero)
                     for i in range(min(len(list1), len(list2)))}
    return all(lista)

def Anmol(list1, list2):
    for a, b in zip(list1,list2):
        if a and b:
            return False
    return True

def Kelly(list1, list2):
    return not any(compress(list2, list1))

def bench(label, list1, list2):
    print(label)
    for func in [Pietr, Anmol, Kelly] * 3:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(list1, list2), number=1))
        print('%7.2f us ' % (t * 1e6), func.__name__)
    print()

bench('worst case', [0,0,1] * 10000, [0,1,0] * 10000)
bench('best case', [1,0,1] * 10000, [1,1,0] * 10000)
```

Comment: The problem with compress from itertools is that if I change the zero it would get me false. For example: lst1 = [1, 7, 2, 7, 4, 5]
lst2 = [7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7] should get me True for zero = 7

Comment: True but since when is 7 zero? :-). Anyway, maybe still useful for future readers. And I just can't pass up an opportunity to showcase `compress`, never seems to get any love from anyone except me...